# Write a script that prints from a dir k strokes sorted by date

Tags: bash, unix

I have a directory "Main Dir" and I want to write a script, which will get 2 parameters: sorted_by_date  , that will find in the directory the id-worker directory (it does exist) and in it, from a file called "sent.txt", it will print results-num (an integer) strokes sorted by date.

I'm a begginer in bash (have knowledge and skills mainly in C), and I stil didn't saw how to write scripts, but I've tried to do something from a little commands I learned and from a little search in the internet.

Can somebody help a newbie like me in my first script-writing ?

I'll paste here my first try:

```
#!/bin/bash

id_worker = "$1" 
results_num = "$2"
sort -k3 -t  "./Main Dir/id_worker/sent.text"
head -n+3 $results_num
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean "*sorted_by_date , that will find in the directory the id-worker directory*"? How are the contents of the `id_worker` variable and the *id-worker directory* related? Are they the same? If you have `id_worker` why are you sorting in order to find the directory you already have a name to? -- confused... Are you saying you want to get the *strokes* for each worker and then sort the strokes by some date contained in `sent.txt`? (please post the sample contents of `sent.txt` that you are interested in retrieving and sorting)

Comment: Ok. I'll make it a little bit clearer. In main directory I have directories which called as the names of my workers in the company: David, Alex, Jhon and so on. I want to write to the terminal sorted_by_date "worker name" "interger" and t get from a file that exists in the directory, which belongs to the worker (by his name), "integer" strokes sorted by dated. 

(there are other type of content like email, time and so on - what the matter is that the 3 column containes the dates.

Comment: Ok, better, but where do the dates you are interested come from? Are they the create/mod times on the directories, or are they contained in the sent.txt file in some format? (or are they the create/mod time of sent.txt)? The folks here are great at coding, but are terrible at mind-reading `:)`

Comment: Sorry, at first I entered "Enter" before I wrote the whole text of my comment )

Comment: Is it clear now ? If it isn't I'll write all formally as it written in the instructions.

Comment: Clearer - You want to search each directory under your `main_dir` within each of your `workers_name` dirs for information in `sent.txt` and then sort that information (1) `by date` (found in sent.txt?), then (2) `by name of worker` listing the number of strokes found in `sent.txt`?? That's very doable, but we need to know where this `date` comes from, and what the format of `sent.txt` looks like (for the relevant data -- `strokes`) you want to get from it. Just edit your question and post the relevant lines from `sent.txt` so we will know how to parse it.

Comment: Yes, but only by date, each worker has his dir in the main dir. I give to my script worker's name and amount of strokes to print from sent.txt and it finds the workers directory, sort in it sent.txt by date and prints the amount of strokes I asked for. Now, in sent.txt the format is day /t email /t date /t time and it is full-filled already.

Comment: OK, it is getting clearer, you say you want to give it the *amount of strokes to print from* `sent.txt`, but then say `sent.txt` has a format of `day /t email /t date /t time`. When you say `strokes` what are you talking about? Does each line in each persons `sent.txt` represent `1-stroke`. So when you say `amount of strokes to print from sent.txt` do you mean the number of `lines` to print from `sent.txt`? Please post at least 10 lines by editing your question and adding that information (I'll reformat it for you if you have a problem)

Comment: can you create small sample data file for 1 id_worker, then show the reduced output you need from that file? Please edit such info into your question, using the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here, and assume your `sort` command is producing the information you want from the `id_worker` `sent.txt` file and that you are talking about the number of `lines` you want when you say `strokes`. Given the extended discussion in the comments, that is about the only thing I see that makes sense.

With that in mind, you were not that far off in your first attempt. What you needed to do to fix the `sort` command was to dereference your `id_worker` with `$` to get the value you passed. In bash you assign variables as `id_worker="something"`, but to get the value back, you must precede the variable with a `$`, just as you see with your `id_worker="$1"`. **NOTE:** there are *NO* spaces allowed on either side of the `'='` sign in bash. Putting that together, it looks like you intended:

```
sort -k3 -t  "./Main Dir/$id_worker/sent.text"
```

Where you are beginning in the directory above `Main Dir` running your script because you have given a **relative** path `"./Main Dir/stuff"`.

Now if you want to limit the number of lines to the first `results_num` lines of the sorted output, then you can use `head`, but you need to remove the `"+"` sign (which is only relevant with the `tail` command). To use it with the sorted output, you must`pipe` the results of `sort` to `head` using the `'|'` pipe character. For example:

```
sort -k3 -t  "./Main Dir/$id_worker/sent.text" | head -n $results_num
```

Putting all of the pieces that I think you intended, and including a short check to make sure both `id_worker` and `results_num` are given on the command line, you would end up with something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

## verify both arguments given
[ -z $1 -o -z $2 ] && {
    printf "error: insufficient input. usage: %s worker num\n" "${0##*/}"
    exit 1
}

id_worker="$1" 
results_num="$2"

## pipe the results of sort to head to print first $results_num lines
sort -k3 -t  "./Main Dir/$id_worker/sent.text" | head -n $results_num
```

**Note:** if you are having trouble with your script, run it with:

```
bash -x scriptname id_worker results_num
```

to enable line-by-line debugging output from bash. Let me know if I have not understood what you were saying or if the results are not what you intended. There are several ways of approaching this problem, but I do need to clearly understand what you want to go further. Good luck.